# Conditional 2nd type, with might; what tense is it referring to?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

If I tell this to someone:

**If you asked me nicely, I might get you a drink.**

Do I mean '**Please** ask nicely, and I get you a drink' or am I emphasizing that 'you have already asked me but it was not nicely' ?

Comment: |It all depends on the context and whether someone has (or has not) already asked you.

Comment: Thank you Ronald, so can I say this sentence to someone in an impromptu manner, when I want to urge them to ask me nicely ?

Comment: You certainly can, but don't say it to your boss!

Comment: Hilarious, sure sir!

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you asked me nicely, I might get you a drink.*

This means: *Please ask nicely, and I'll perhaps get you a drink.*

(In practice it usually means "will", but in principle it is caveated with "might", so formally means "will perhaps".)

*If you'd asked me nicely, I might have got/gotten you a drink.*

This means: *You didn't ask nicely, so you haven't got one* - although of course, the addressee might nevertheless take this as their cue to ask again (nicely this time) and the other person might then relent.